# Need help understanding what this data analysis code (for optics lab) is doing

Tags: python, physics, waveform

I am working in an undergraduate optics lab and we were given a few codes for data analysis. I need help understanding what two of them are doing exactly. To give some background on the experiment: light from a pulsed laser is injected into the back of a PTFE diffuser. Across from the diffuser is a photomultiplier tube that detects the optical signal. During the experiment, the diffuser is rotated and data is collected about the pulse waveform for every three degrees. I am just not sure what the code does to interpret this data, I hope that makes sense. Thank you in advance.

Here is the first code:

```
import numpy as np

DEFAULT_FMAX = 0.2

class Waveform(object):
def __init__(self, X, Y, fmax=None, peaknorm=False, areanorm=False):
    self.X = np.copy(X)
    self.Y = np.copy(Y)
    if fmax is not None:
        self.lowpass_filter(fmax)
    if peaknorm:
        self.normalise_peak()
    if areanorm:
        self.normalise_area()

def lowpass_filter(self, fmax):
    # Fourier transform
    freq_Y = np.fft.rfft(self.Y)
    freq_X = np.fft.rfftfreq(self.Y.size, d=((max(self.X)-min(self.X))/self.Y.size))
    # Apply max frequency cut
    freq_Y[freq_X>fmax] = 0.0
    # Inverse fourier transform
    self.Y = np.fft.irfft(freq_Y)

def normalise_peak(self):
    self.Y /= abs(np.min(self.Y))

def normalise_area(self):
    self.Y /= np.sum(self.Y)

@property
def fft(self):
    freq_Y = np.fft.rfft(self.Y)
    freq_X = np.fft.rfftfreq(self.Y.size, d=((max(self.X)-min(self.X))/self.Y.size))
    return freq_X, freq_Y

@property
def pedestal(self):
    return np.mean(self.Y[0:100])

@property
def amplitude(self):
    return abs(min(self.Y) - self.pedestal)

@property
def peak_index(self):
    return np.argmin(self.Y)        
    
@property
def peak_time(self):
    return self.X[self.peak_index]

def _find_half_maxima_indices(self):
    peak = self.peak_index
    Y = np.copy(self.Y - self.pedestal)
    Y += (self.amplitude / 2.0)
    # find first half maximum
    try:
        first = np.argmax(Y[:peak] < 0)
    except ValueError:
        # can fail eg if peak == 0            
        first = peak
    try:
        second = peak + np.argmax(Y[peak:] > 0)
    except ValueError:
        # can fail eg if peak == last bin            
        second = peak
    return first, second

@property
def fwhm(self):
    return self.rise + self.fall

@property
def fall(self):
    _, second = self._find_half_maxima_indices()
    fall = self.X[second] - self.peak_time
    return fall

@property
def rise(self):
    first, _ = self._find_half_maxima_indices()
    rise = self.peak_time - self.X[first]
    return rise


@property
def integralindex_high(self):
    pedestal = self.pedestal
    #integrate falling edge
    for ii in range(self.peak_index, self.Y.shape[0] - 1):
        if (self.Y[ii] - pedestal) > 0.0:
            break
    return ii

@property
def integralindex_low(self):
    pedestal = self.pedestal
    #integrate falling edge
    ii = 0
    for ii in reversed(range(0, self.peak_index)):
        if (self.Y[ii] - pedestal) > 0.0:
            break
    return ii

@property
def area(self):
    area = 0.0
    pedestal = self.pedestal
    #integrate falling edge
    for ii in range(self.peak_index, self.integralindex_high):
        area += (self.Y[ii] - pedestal) * (self.X[ii + 1] - self.X[ii])
    #integrate rising edge
    for ii in reversed(range(self.integralindex_low, self.peak_index)):
        area += (self.Y[ii] - pedestal) * (self.X[ii + 1] - self.X[ii])
    return abs(area)
```

And the second:

```
import ROOT
import numpy as np
import datetime
from collections import namedtuple
from collections import defaultdict
from .waveform import Waveform

class ScanPoint:
def __init__(self, time_epoch, coord_angle, coord_y, lab_temp, lab_humid, dt, samples_PMT, 
samples_PD, num_entry):
    self.time_epoch = time_epoch
    self.coord_angle = coord_angle
    self.coord_y = coord_y
    self.lab_temp = lab_temp
    self.lab_humid = lab_humid
    self.samples_PMT = np.array(list(samples_PMT), dtype=float)
    self.samples_PD = np.array(list(samples_PD), dtype=float)
    self.axis_time = np.arange(len(samples_PMT), dtype=float) * dt * 1.e9
    self.num_entry = num_entry

def getWaveformPMT(self, fmax=None, peaknorm=False, areanorm=False):
  return Waveform(self.axis_time, self.samples_PMT, fmax, peaknorm, areanorm)

def getWaveformPD(self, fmax=None, peaknorm=False, areanorm=False):
  return Waveform(self.axis_time, self.samples_PD, fmax, peaknorm, areanorm)

def getDatetime(self):
  return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(self.time_epoch)

# Tuple containing metadata and scanpoints for a full scan
DiffuserScan = namedtuple("DiffuserScan", ["ID_diffuser",
                                       "ID_PMT",
                                       "ID_PD",
                                       "ID_lightsource",
                                       "ID_experimentalist",
                                       "notes",
                                       "pulse_rate",
                                       "pulse_N",
                                       "scanpoints"])

def readscan(filename, treename):
file = ROOT.TFile.Open(filename, "READ")
tree = getattr(file, treename)

tree.GetEntry(0)

formatversion = (
    int(tree.version_major),
    int(tree.version_minor),
    int(tree.version_patch),
)

# Check that input file format is implemented
if formatversion[:2] == (1, 0):
    diffuserscan = DiffuserScan(
        str(tree.ID_diffuser),
        str(tree.ID_PMT),
        str(tree.ID_PD),
        str(tree.ID_lightsource),
        str(tree.ID_experimentalist),
        str(tree.notes),
        float(tree.pulse_rate),
        int(tree.pulse_N),
        [],
    )

    for i, entry in enumerate(tree):
        scanpoint = ScanPoint(entry.time_epoch,
                              entry.coord_angle,
                              entry.coord_y,
                              entry.lab_temp,
                              entry.lab_humid,
                              entry.dt,
                              entry.waveform_PMT,
                              entry.waveform_PD,
                              i)

        diffuserscan.scanpoints.append(scanpoint)

else:
    raise NotImplementedError("Input format version not implemented")

return diffuserscan

def combinefiles(scans):
combined_scan = scans[0]
compare_vars = ["ID_PMT", "ID_PD", "ID_lightsource", "pulse_rate", "pulse_N"]
for scan in scans[1:]:
    combined_scan.scanpoints.extend(scan.scanpoints)
    if scan.ID_diffuser != combined_scan.ID_diffuser:
        combined_scan.ID_diffuser = "multi"
    for var in compare_vars:
        if getattr(scan, var) != getattr(combined_scan, var):
            print('WARNING: Variable "{}" does not match between files! Should we be comparing 
them?'.format(var))

return combined_scan
```

Comment: Sorry, but SO doesn't work like that. Please take a Python tutorial and ask specific questions. Also, try to find a video tutorial how to use a debugger, that is an invaluable tool when exploring code. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).